# Deleting selected cells in uicollectionview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have placed a button within a uicollectionviewcell and when that button is pressed, it is programmatically setting the cell as selected.

```
- (void) deleteItem:(id)sender
{
    self.selected = YES;
    [self.cellOptionsDelegate deleteItem];
}
```

It then delegates to the uicollectionviewcontroller to deleted the item that is selected.

```
- (void) deleteItem
{
    NSArray* selectedItemsIndexPaths = [self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems];

    // Delete the items from the data source.
    [self.taskArray removeObjectAtIndex:[[selectedItemsIndexPaths objectAtIndex:0] row]];

    // Now delete the items from the collection view.
    [self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:selectedItemsIndexPaths];

}
```

However, when i get the selected items using the uicollectionview method indexPathsForSelectedItems, it is not seeing that I have selected the item and the list is empty. I am using the press to select delegate method for another functionality so I was hoping to do something along the lines of what I explained above. Is there a way to make this work or a better way to inform the controller that the button pressed in the cell was tied to a cell at a specific index path?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just send a cell pointer from your cell's deleteItem method

```
- (void) deleteItem:(id)sender
{
    self.selected = YES;
    [self.cellOptionsDelegate deleteItem:self];
}
```

and change uicollectionviewcontroller's method to

```
- (void) deleteItem:(UICollectionViewCell*)cellToDelete
{
    NSIndexPath indexPathToDelete = [self indexPathForCell: cellToDelete];

    // Delete the items from the data source.
    [self.taskArray removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPathToDelete row]];

    // Now delete the items from the collection view.
    [self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPathToDelete]];

}
```

Do not forget to update '(void) deleteItem:(UICollectionViewCell*)cellToDelete' declaration in your *.h file.

Comment: This will only delete a single cell. How to delete multiple selected cells in one go on the tap of some button?

Answer (score 1):

Solved by sending the cell through the delegate method and using this:

```
    NSIndexPath* indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForCell:cell];
```

Answer (score 0):

> animated:

```
[self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^ {
      [_array removeObject:file];            
      [self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]];
} completion:nil];
```